# Something is amiss in my timespan code

Tags: vb.net, datetime

My code is as follows:

```
    Private Sub tbRcvrDepartTime_textchanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbRcvrDepartTime.TextChanged

    'Converts the 90 Receiver Arrival & Departures Date & Times to a string for comparison
    Dim raTime As String = tbRcvrArriveTime.Text            'Takes the Time only String and converts to string
    Dim raDate As String = dpRcvrArriveDate.Text            'Takes the DateTimePicker and converts date to string
    Dim raDateString = String.Concat(raDate, " ", raTime)   'Puts together the Date & Time into one continuous string
    'Dim raDateFormat As String = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"         'Sets the String to Date style Format
    Dim raResultDate As Date = CDate(raDateString)          'Finalizes the String for use in below comparison

    Dim rdTime As String = tbRcvrDepartTime.Text            'Takes the Time only String and converts to string
    Dim rdDate As String = dpRcvrDepartDate.Text            'Takes the DateTimePicker and converts date to string
    Dim rdDateString = String.Concat(rdDate, " ", rdTime)   'Puts together the Date & Time into one continuous string
    'Dim rdDateFormat As String = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"         'Sets the String to Date Format
    Dim rdResultDate As Date = CDate(rdDateString)          'Finalizes the String for use in below comparison

    'Checks to see if 2 or more hours have elapsed since Receiver Arrival/Departure Date & Time
    Dim elapsedR As TimeSpan = rdResultDate.Subtract(raResultDate)
    tbRcvrDepartTime.BackColor = If(elapsedR.TotalMinutes > 120, Color.LightPink, Color.White)
End Sub
```

Both raTime & rdTime are separate textboxes.
Both raDate & rdDate are datetimepickers.

When I run the code "live" initially the first record I look at is displayed correctly. Once I move to another record, this goes out the window... I get random results where it will not change the backcolor to the proper color if >120 minutes has elapsed. Other times it changes the backcolor when there is <120 minutes elapsed. Sometimes no change in backcolor when it should or it will change color when it should not. I attempted to originally do this using TotalHours but met with the same results. It is random and is not consistent. I have worked on this for 2 days now with no difference in results. My thinking is there needs to be a way to "refresh" the rdResultDate & raResultDate info when each new record is loaded but I am unable to do that with my code knowledge.

The code must be able to take into account if a new date is present - ie raDate: 11/01/2016 and raTime: 23:46 and 
rdDate: 11/02/2016 and rdTime: 03:00 - this would exceed 2 hours (or 120 minutes) and should read "True" and change the backcolor as it is over 2 hours (or 120 minutes).

However if the following were true:
raDate: 11/01/2016 and raTime: 23:46 and
rdDate: 11/02/2016 and rdTime: 01:00 this would not exceed 2 hours (or 120 minutes) and should read "False" and would not change the backcolor.

Answer (score 0):

All of this code:

```
Dim Detention90 As String

Try
    If elapsedR.TotalMinutes > 120 Then
        Detention90 = "True"
    Else
        Detention90 = "False"
    End If

    Select Case Detention90.ToString
        Case = "True" : tbRcvrDepartTime.BackColor = Color.LightPink
        Case Else : tbRcvrDepartTime.BackColor = Color.White
    End Select

Catch ex As Exception
    'If a problem occurs, show Error message box
    MessageBox.Show("Receiver Arrive Time & Depart Time Elapsed error" & vbCrLf & "Lines 1424-1434")
End Try
```

condenses down to just this:

```
Dim elapsedR As TimeSpan = rdResultDate.Subtract(raResultDate)
tbRcvrDepartTime.BackColor = If(elapsedR.TotalMinutes > 120, Color.LightPink, Color.White)
```

Not sure if it will directly address your issue, but it was a bit too much for a comment and I've found compacting code in this way is often extremely beneficial for tracking down difficult bugs.

But in this case, I suspect the main issue is parsing the datetime values... that you're not always parsing the DateTime value you expect from a given input string. Specifically, you have format string variables `raDateFormat` and `rdDateFormat`, but then call `Date.Parse()` such that these format variables are **never** used, and you are left at the mercy of whatever the default date format is for your thread, process, or system. If you're on a system that uses a d/m/y order as in the UK instead of the US-style m/d/y, you'll end up with some strange results. You probably want `DateTime.ParseExact()` instead.

Comment: Tried the ParseExact and it in no way liked that. I disabled the rdDateFormat and raDateFormat variable hoping this would resolve but no luck. I have updated the code in original msg to reflect the suggested changes. I am still coming up with random colorizing of the background so it seems the elapsedR variable is not right - even if I run it in debug the format appears correct.